# Scope of using namespace versus using namespace closure

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, definition, name-lookup

I'm trying to understand why there is ambiguity in my functions when I use using namespace versus explicitly declaring a namespace enclosure.

Book.h header file:

```
#ifndef MYBOOK_BOOK_H
#define MYBOOK_BOOK_H 

namespace mybook
{
    void showTitle();
    void showTableOfContents();
}

#endif
```

My implmenetation file which causes an ambiguity error:
Book.cpp

```
#include "Book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using namespace mybook;

void showTitle() {
    cout << "The Happy Penguin" << endl;
    cout << "By John Smith" << endl;
}

void showTableOfContents() {
     cout << "Chapter 1" << endl;
     cout << "Chapter 2" << endl;
}
```

My implementation file which does not have an ambiguity error:
Book.cpp

```
#include "Book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

namespace mybook {

   void showTitle() {
       cout << "The Happy Penguin" << endl;
       cout << "By John Smith" << endl;
   }

   void showTableOfContents() {
        cout << "Chapter 1" << endl;
        cout << "Chapter 2" << endl;
   }
}
```

I would think that the first scenario of Book.cpp should work because by declaring using namespace mybook at the beginning it is saying that I am now going to implement the functions I defined in the header file. However I get the errors of "error 'showTitle': ambiguous call to overload function could be 'void showTitle(void) or void mybook::showTitle(void)'" and same for my other function showTableOfContents. Why does using namespace mybook in the first scenario not work?

Comment: Never use "using namespace std". You shouldn't try to figure out how to get it to work and instead just get rid of that practice.

Comment: And don't use C headers such as cstring. Use string and the proper tools you have in C++.

Comment: Some context for Eric's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/26722134#26722134

Note that some people disagree with the idea that you should *never* use `using namespace std`.

Comment: @Rosme While it is good advice to prefer `std::string` over C strings, not using C headers in general is not good advice. For example there is nothing wrong with using stuff from `<cmath>`, `<cstdint>`, `<cstddef>` and many others. In OP's case (although it is currently unused) `<cctype>` also has valid uses, since there are no C++ equivalents for most of the functions it offers.

Comment: @walnut True. I shouldn't have said that in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These definitions

```
using namespace std;
using namespace mybook;

void showTitle() {
    cout << "The Happy Penguin" << endl;
    cout << "By John Smith" << endl;
}

void showTableOfContents() {
     cout << "Chapter 1" << endl;
     cout << "Chapter 2" << endl;
}
```

declare two functions in the global namespace.

So now you have four functions in the global namespace and in the namespace `mybook` that have identical declarations and due to including the using directive

```
using namespace mybook;
```

the unqualified name lookup finds all four functions. As a result the compiler reports about ambiguity.

If you want to define the functions that were declared in the namespace **mybook** then you have to write

```
using namespace std;
using namespace mybook;

void mybook::showTitle() {
    cout << "The Happy Penguin" << endl;
    cout << "By John Smith" << endl;
}

void mybook::showTableOfContents() {
     cout << "Chapter 1" << endl;
     cout << "Chapter 2" << endl;
}
```

that is you need to use qualified names.

From the C++ 17 Standard (10.3.1.2 Namespace member deﬁnitions)

> **2 Members of a named namespace can also be deﬁned outside that namespace by explicit qualiﬁcation** (6.4.3.2) of the name being
>   deﬁned, provided that the entity being deﬁned was already declared in
>   the namespace and the deﬁnition appears after the point of declaration
>   in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s namespace.

and (7.3.4 Using directive)

> 3 A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative region
>   in which it appears

Pay attention to that the ambiguity occurred due to unqualified name lookup.

If you used a qualified name lookup then the compiler found the functions declared in the global namespace (in which case the program would executed successfully) or in the namespace `mybook` (in this case the compiler or linker would report an error that the functions are not defined).

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace mybook
{
    void f1();
    void f2();
}

using namespace mybook;

void f1() { std::cout << "::f1();\n"; }
void f2() { std::cout << "::f2();\n"; }

int main() 
{
    ::f1();
    ::f2();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
::f1();
::f2();
```

If you would write

```
mybook::f1();
mybook::f2();
```

then an error will occur that the functions are not defined.

Comment: Thank you the examples helped to illustrate to me where I was making a mistake in my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

> I would think that the first scenario of Book.cpp should work because by declaring using namespace mybook at the beginning it is saying that I am now going to implement the functions I defined in the header file.

That is where you are incorrect.  `using namespace mybook;` says you are using the names from `mybook`, not that you are defining/adding names to `mybook`.  To define names in `mybook` you need to open the namespace and put the definitions in it like you do in your second example.